# In jackson 2.8, how can I postprocess every deserialized value of class Foo?

Tags: java, jackson

I'm building a rest service using jackson with a single instance of ObjectMapper where I can set my configuration. Java-side values are pojos with fields of types like String and int. Very simple, straightforward situation, nothing special.

I want to perform some processing on every field of a given type after deserialization, possibly altering the value that should be put in the pojo field. I don't want to litter my pojos with annotations or anything, it should be self-contained within ObjectMapper. I also don't want to override the existing deserialization code - the data mapping itself should keep working as-is.

Concrete example: say I want to call toUpperCase() on every incoming String because I dislike lower case letters. How can I create this behavior? I was hoping to find something like the following, but it doesn't seem to exist:

`objectMapper.getDeserializationConfig().registerValueProcessor(Foo.class, Foo::bar);`

I'm familiar with jackson basics like registering a new type (de)serializer, I just don't know anything for this particular type of thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best thing to do would be to write my own (de)serializer impl that wraps around an existing (de)serializer, using inheritance or composition, and replaces it in the objectmapper configuration. That way I can call the original conversion logic (through super or a field) and postprocess the result it returns.

Answer (score 0):

> Concrete example: say I want to call `toUpperCase()` on every incoming `String` because I dislike lower case letters. How can I create this behavior?

Create your custom deserializer for `String`:

```java
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("customDeserializers", Version.unknownVersion());
module.addDeserializer(String.class, new StdDeserializer<String>(String.class) {

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        return jp.getValueAsString().toUpperCase();
    }
});

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(module);
```

The custom deserializer defined above will process only values mapped to `String`. If a given POJO has a member where its type is `UUID`, for instance, the value won't be converted to upper case. See the example below:

```java
public class Person {

    private UUID id;

    private String name;

    // Getters and setters
}
```

```java
String json = "{\"id\": \"6d39b716-ee80-4468-b1e4-b4270d57be99\", \"name\": \"Joe Doe\"}";
Person person = mapper.readValue(json, Person.class);

System.out.println(person.getId());   // Prints 6d39b716-ee80-4468-b1e4-b4270d57be99
System.out.println(person.getName()); // Prints JOE DOE
```

Comment: "I also don't want to override the existing deserialization code - the data mapping itself should keep working as-is." A custom deserializer would need to implement its own json-to-java conversion logic, getValueAsString() in this case. I want to leave existing type mapping (e.g. for bigdecimals or uuids or any arbitrary type) untouched. I only want to define after-the-fact enrichment logic.

Comment: @Marnes Have you tried the solution I've described in my answer? The custom deserializer will process only values mapped to `String`. If a given POJO has a member where its type is `UUID`, for instance, it won't be converted to upper case.

Comment: I can't check it out right now, later. The problem is my processing (toUpperCase) needs to be independent of the actual mapping from json to java. Your example only works for strings because you rely on getValueAsString(). Say I need to call bar() on a Foo foo after it has been converted from a json structure to a Foo object, how can that work like this? JsonParser doesn't provide a method to get the current mapped value of an arbitrary type, only the json data. My enricher needs to come after a deserializer has done its work, so the enricher can't be a deserializer impl. Chicken/egg problem.

Comment: @Marnes _"The problem is my processing (toUpperCase) needs to be independent of the actual mapping from json to java."_ It's not Jackson's  problem then. Handle it in your service layer.

Comment: Depends. I want to add a step to an existing deserialization process without undermining or overriding the existing deserialization logic. It's a luxury feature but it's certainly relevant, it's basically enriching the objects produced by the objectmapper. Having to handle the enrichment for every field of its type in service layers would lead to piles of repetitive code. Jackson provides annotations to specify all sorts of details for mapping, like date formats, so this isn't far-fetched.